# How do I logout users that have been afk for 10 minutes?

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote this script but it doesnt seem to work. even tho mysqli_num_rows is > 1, no user get logged out.
online=0 = user is offline.

```
<?php

include_once 'db.php';

$res = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT username FROM users WHERE last_active<= NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE"); 

$row=mysqli_fetch_array($res);
$user = $row['username'];

mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users SET online=0 WHERE username='$user'");
?>
```

Comment: Does it set `online` correctly?

Comment: where is your session management code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just run a query like this:

> "UPDATE users SET online = 0 WHERE last_active<= NOW() - INTERVAL 10
>   MINUTE"

oh, assuming you have code somewhere else that will actually put them "offline" if their online field = 0...